# Why was Urû'baen built under an outcropping?

Tags: inheritance-cycle

The city of Urû'baen in the Inheritance Cycle, when it was Ilirea, was built under an outcropping that covers much of the city, which, as [this answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/280911/51379) indicates, is held up by magic. Based on what we know about the energy requirements for magic, even given elves' higher fortitude, it would likely have taken countless magicians years or decades to use magic to hollow out the rock while using magic to buttress it against collapse.

That is a lot of effort for a structure that is vulnerable to magical sabotage—a single magician could not efficiently collapse the whole thing, but could possibly break off sufficiently dangerous portions—and that leaves much of the city in shadow. Not to mention that it goes against every rule of traditional elven aesthetics.

Why did the builders choose to construct Ilirea under a rock outcropping?

Comment: I'm guessing is because it looks cool. I reckon at least 10% of my life choices (both good and bad) have been made for that reason.

Comment: To be clear, the magic isn't the only thing holding it up. The magic is just there to make it stronger and to avoid the risks of parts randomly falling off, or of it collapsing if a suicidal monarch decides to detonate a nuke in his throne room. Things like that.

Answer (score 5):

### As defense against Dragon attacks, and also because of the prophecy-inducing fumes in that spot

In Inheritance, Galbatorix lectures to Nasuada about the history of the city and the room she is being held in.

> Then he gestured at the room with his gauntlets. “Before we proceed, you should know something of the history of this place. When the elves first ventured to this part of the world, they discovered a crevice buried deep within the escarpment that looms over the plains hereabout. The escarpment they prized as defense against the attacks of dragons, but the crevice they prized for an entirely different reason. By happenstance, they discovered that the vapors rising out of the crack in the stone increased the chances that those who slept near it might catch a glimpse, if however confused, of future events. So, over two and a half thousand years ago, the elves built this room atop the fissure, and an oracle came to live here for many hundreds of years, even after the elves abandoned the rest of Ilirea. She sat where you now lie, and she whiled away the centuries dreaming of all that had been and all that might be.
> In time, the air lost its potency and the oracle and her attendants departed.
> <sub>*Inheritance* - "The Hall of the Soothsayer"</sub>

So the original elvish settlement of Ilirea was built in this spot for two reasons:

- The rock outcropping over the city provided protection from the dragons (this was prior to the formation of the Dragon Riders, and dragon attacks were something elves would frequently need to worry about).
- Underneath the outcropping was a fissure from which prophecy-inducing fumes were emerging, which led the Soothsayer and her attendants to set up in that spot.

Eventually, the elves and dragons made peace, and the fumes dried up causing the soothsayer to leave, and so the city was abandoned. When the humans were looking for a new capitol, they took it over, as it was already built up and was center to the new Broddring Kingdom.

Comment: The exact nature of these fumes is explored a bit more in the new *Murtagh* book, though this answer would remain the same.

Comment: I guess the implication here is also that the magic that holds up the rock was *not* from the elves.

Comment: @Adamant - The magic is said to be from the elves. "*...while they waited to see if the overhang would break and fall. That it had not, the elves told Eragon, was because of spells they had embedded within the stone in ages past—when Urû’baen was yet known as Ilirea—and also because of the overhang’s sheer size, which had allowed it to weather the force of the blast without significant damage.*". (*Inheritance* - "Heir to the Empire")